# perl pass object method reference as parameter to function

Tags: perl, methods

i'm trying to do something like this:

-- source file 1

```
my $queue = Thread::Queue->new();
MyModules::populateQueue(<pass $queue->enqueue method reference);
...
```

-- package file

```
package MyModules

sub populateQueue {
  my $enqueue = $_[0];
  my $item = <find item to add to queue>;
  $enqueue->($item);
```

...

first, i'm not able to add "bless" to Thread::Queue

i've tried a couple of suggestions i found in stackoverflow:

```
my $enqueueRef = $queue->can('enqueue');
MyModules::populateQueue(\&enqueueRef); <--- fails in the package at line
```

$enqueue->($item) with undefined subroutine

```
MyModules::populateQueue(\&queue->enqueue) <-- same failure as above
```

any idea how to pass a method of an object as a parameter to a function that can then be used in the function?

Comment: just wrap it around sub: `sub { $queue->enqueue; }`

Comment: There's also the `curry` module on CPAN.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl doesn't have a concept of a bound method reference. `my $enqueue = $object->can('method')` will return a code ref to a method if it exists, but the code ref isn't bound to that particular object – you still need to pass it as the first argument (`$queue->$enqueue($item)` or `$enqueue->($queue, $item)`).

To pass a bound method, the correct solution is to use an anonymous sub that wraps the method call:

```
populate_queue(sub { $queue->enqueue(@_) });
```

Comment: just to add clarity, i did the following in the MyModules package:
MyModules::populateQueue(sub {$queue->enqueue(@_)});
which works.